# Какова правильная интерпретация сообщения "Creating network "XXX" with the default driver" при запуске Docker-а?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Пытаюсь запустить первое своё приложение на Docker-e, а не учебный пример. Как обычно, этот процесс сопровождается большим количеством проблем и непонятных моментов, не рассматриваемых в учебных видео.

Анализирую вывод сообщений при первом запуске Docker-а.

```
D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXXX\ProjectsForFunctionalTesting\FullStackWebApplication-NodeJS>docker-compose up -d
Creating network "fullstackwebapplication-nodejs_default" with the default driver
```

Первое же сообщение порождает 7 вопросов:

- Какую сеть он создаёт?
- Зачем он её создаёт?
- А есть ли в этом необходимость?
- Какой такой драйвер про умолчанию?
- Зачем в данном контексте нужен драйвер?
- Какие ещё бывают драйвера?
- Если мне об этом (создании сети) так важно знать, то какая от меня требуется реакция на это замечательное сообщение?

Мой `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  webpack:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./00-Source:/Application/00-Source
      - ./01-DevelopmentBuild:/Application/01-DevelopmentBuild
      - ./.eslintignore:/Application/.eslintignore
      - ./.eslintrc.yaml:/Application/.eslintrc.yaml
      - ./.mocharc.yaml:/Application/.mocharc.yaml
      - ./package.json:/Application/package.json
      - ./tsconfig.json:/Application/tsconfig.json
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Мой `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.4

WORKDIR /Application

RUN npm i

CMD [ "npm", "run", "'Incremental development build'" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Какую сеть он создаёт? Зачем он её создаёт?

Он создает сеть к которой будут подключены все сервисы, которые находятся в `docker-compose.yml`.

> А есть ли в этом необходимость?

Это упрощает взаимодействие между сервисами (контейнерами), т.к. в дефолтной сети (к которой подключаются контейнеры при создании например через `docker run`), не работает DNS Discovery, тогда как в остальных сетях созданных пользователем все ок. Это позволяет использоваться названия сервисов для коммуникации, а не IP. Например, если в вашем сервисе стартует сервер, то к нему можно будет получить доступ через: `http://webpack/...`.

> Какой такой драйвер про умолчанию? Зачем в данном контексте нужен драйвер?

Драйвер по умолчанию: `bridge`. Драйверы позволяют создавать разные "типы" сетей, от их различиях можно посмотреть в документации.

> Какие ещё бывают драйвера?

[Документация](https://docs.docker.com/network/#network-drivers)

> Если мне об этом (создании сети) так важно знать, то какая от меня требуется реакция на это замечательное сообщение?

Никакой, это просто информативное сообщение, чтобы вы знали, что была создана сеть.

> первое своё приложение на Docker-e, а не учебный пример

Если это приложение, а не учебный пример, то скорее все что указано в `volume` не нужно монтировать в контейнер, а указываться в `Dockerfile` через `COPY`.

Comment: Канонический ответ! Благодарю Вас. "а указываться в Dockerfile через COPY" - подскажите пожалуйста, а как тогда в этом случае обеспечить копирование обновлённых файлов? По мере добавления новый строк кода моё приложение будет пересобираться и Docker должен об этом знать.

Comment: @БоковГлеб собирать каждый раз новый образ (руками или через CI/CD), ваш подход применим только при разработке, но когда вы захотите задеплоить реальное приложение так не делают, образ должен быть самодостаточным и фиксированным, в него должно быть запаковано полностью приложение (внешними могут быть БД или конфиги)